# Wordpress Migration issue with DB password

Tags: wordpress, migration

I am in the process of migrating some WordPress sites to a new server. The first three websites went with out a hitch. While working on the fourth site I migrated over the database and files. When editing the config file I put in the new information. Then I loaded the site to see if the migration worked and I get a HTTP error 500. When I change the password to the incorrect password I get the error establishing database connection.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I too faced that error once. 
In my situation it occurred because i forget to change the permalinks to numerical values in old hosting server. Http 500 error generally shows up when that page doesn't exists on server. Therefore you have to change the permalinks in old hosting first then export the sql file to new server and import it there.  then it might work.